# How experienced is my parens?

Tags: ars-magica-5

I have a number of players using overly-complex character creation. While it is possible to take the 240 xp from detailed and map it to overly-complex during apprenticeship, there are a number of hard-to-swallow abstractions.

One of the most problematic is the abstraction of teaching spells. A huge number of spells can be *taught* in a season, as a function of the lab total of the teacher. What is a fair way to estimate the experience of a parens such that an overly-complex character doesn't have an undue advantage and doesn't involve simply building the parens from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

If a character already has their final scores in magical arts, you could add 2d6+10 (or some other pseudo-random value) to get the parens score in that art. *So, if I have a muto of 20, my parens would have 37 on average.*  Of course, just because a parens can know a spell does not mean that they do.